# bash: "-H" : command not found

Tags: docker, jupyter

I installed DOCKER , and create UBUNTU 20.04 container.

and I want to install jupyterhub, but I can't.

```
root@6586864810d6:/# $sudo -H pip3 install jupyterlab
```

**bash: -H: command not found**

help me.

Comment: Documentation often show a `$` sign at beginning of lines to represent a command prompt, but this is not part of the command to execute: remove the leading `$` of your command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pasting in a command literally with a dollar sign in front of it.

The command you're trying to run is `sudo -H pip3 install jupyterlab`

In an Ubuntu Docker container, you're a root user by default, and there is no `sudo` command. So the command you want is

```sh
pip3 install jupyterlab
```

But Ubuntu doesn't come with pip by default. So first you need to install it:

```sh
apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: thank you Andy!! One more Question.                                                  
 root@6586864810d6:/# $sudo -u tester sudo -n -u $USER /usr/local/bin/sudospawner --help
bash: -u: command not found                                                                                                  Why error??

Comment: You're still copying the dollar sign. Don't copy and paste the dollar sign.The dollar sign represents the shell "prompt". It's a convention that shows the command following the dollar sign is meant to be executed in a shell. If this or another answer helped answer your question, click the empty check mark next to it to help others find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The command should be `sudo -H pip3 install jupyterlab`

However, you have better installation options for Docker by way of ready-made Docker images available for optimal containers for different configurations. These images are maintained by jupuyter team.

```
jupyter/base-notebook
jupyter/minimal-notebook
jupyter/r-notebook
...
```

https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/selecting.html